# trigger visibility of sublist on class change

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've been trying to achieve this for the last two days, but I'm fairly new to javascript, so maybe I'm just not seeing something.

What I'm trying to create is a Sidenavigation, that highlights the current section you are at. I have found a jquery plugin that does that like a charm http://trevordavis.net/blog/jquery-one-page-navigation-plugin/

But I am working with subitems and I would like to trigger the visibility of this subitem, as soon as the current section is active. So the ul would be visible if the containing list item has the class of .current, and if one of the sublist's list items has the class .current.

I have found out, that I'd probably need to trigger an event on the class change. I have tried the following, but it has not yet worked.

Markup:

```
<ul id="nav">
    <li class="current"><a href="#section-1">Section 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#section-2">Section 2</a></li>
    <li class="parent"><a href="#section-3">Section 3</a>
        <ul class="sublist">
            <li><a href="#subsection-1">Subsection 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#subsection-2">Subsection 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#subsection-3">Subsection 3</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

For the jquery I have tried this:

```
$('#nav').on('event', function(){
    $('.parent').addClass('current').trigger('visibility');
});

$('.parent').on('visibility', function(){
    $('.parent .sublist').addClass('visible');
});
```

What I am basically trying to do is what Bootrap does in its documentation. When scrolling down, you can see Glyphicons, as soon as you reached this section, the subitems pop open (available glyphs, how to use, examples) http://getbootstrap.com/components/

SASS applied to the Navigation so far:

```
.overview{
    transition: .3s all;

    ul{
        margin-left: 10px;

            ul{
                max-height: 0;
                transition: max-height 1s ease-out;
                overflow: hidden;
            }
    }
}

.current{
    > a{
        font-weight: $bold;
    }

    ul{
        max-height: 9999px !important;
        transition: max-height 1s ease-out;
    }
}
```

I have been able to show the sublist if the parent is set to current, but as soon as the child is current, the sublist will be hidden, so I figured, I'd need some javascript

Comment: Could you add a fiddle illustrating what you're attempting? It's not entirely clear.

Comment: I added an example where this is done, I cannot illustrate it myself, since I have not figured out how to achive it...

Comment: Do you mean the line at the side of the menu , And bolding applied to the section that is visible?

Comment: no, i mean the fact that the subitems only show, if the section is active. Bolding and the line on the side is something I can handle with CSS.

Comment: Adding a CSS rule `.current .sublist { display: block; }` may do what you want. It would be handy if you could add the relevant CSS to your question to help us replicate your problem.

Comment: @HiddenHobbes that will work if if the parent list item is active, but it won't work when one of the subitems is set to current, I have tried that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see now :)

What you could do, (there's probably multiple way, but what I'd do) is create a function that checks on scroll if a class is nearing the top of the window, if so, add a class to the relating item in the nav bar.

Should be relatively simple to do without a plugin, something along the lines of:

```
  var checkSide = function(){
    $('.container p').each(function(){
      var item = $(this).offset().top,
          $window = $(window),
          navItem = $('#nav a[data-id="'+$(this).data('id')+'"]');

      if ($window.scrollTop() >= item) {
        if (!navItem.hasClass('current')) {
          $('#nav .current').removeClass('current');
          navItem.addClass('current');
        }
      }
    });
  };

  $(window).scroll(function(){
     checkSide(); 
  });
```

See http://codepen.io/jhealey5/pen/GjJFI - Should be able to adapt it to your needs.

Assuming I understood correctly :)

Comment: this does highlight the current item, But can you hide the subitems in the navigation whilst the other first-level items are active?

Comment: Sure, see updated pen. It's not ideal but it's a start for you :)

Comment: gr8, that does waht I want :)
But if I have multiple sections with subitems, this opens up every sublist. What would I have to do if I only want the current sublist to show?

Comment: it does the job. Thanks a lot :D